# Websockets - IE and Chrome differences?

Tags: google-chrome, internet-explorer, firefox, websocket, timeout

On Websocket Disconnection I am getting timeout on IE 11  but Chrome seems to work fine or it might be more tolerance for timeout ? I was wondering what are the differences in behavior in IE , Chrome and FF 
    jfriend00 here is the Code which is behaving differently in IE and Chrome

```
systemError = function(e, detail, msg) {
     var ts = new Date(), prev = false;        
    // Used to throttle messages so we don't bombard the user
    var checkThrottle = function() {
        // See if we know what the last request type was because we should not throttle on 
        // certain reqeust types
        if (dali.lastWSCommand && (dali.lastWSCommand == 'set' || dali.lastWSCommand  == 'del'))
            return false;

        if (errTimes[detail]) {
            prev = errTimes[detail];
        }
        errTimes[detail] = ts;
        if (prev && ((ts - prev) < 10000)) {

            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean "timeout on disconnection"?  Please show code and exact error you get.

Comment: jfriend00 here is the Code which is behaving differently in IE and Chrome